# How to continuosly update the textbox in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have the following piece of code:

```
class NotepadCloneNoMenu : Form
{
    protected TextBox txtbox;

    public NotepadCloneNoMenu(string a)
    {

        Text = "Notepad Clone No Menu";

        txtbox = new TextBox();
        txtbox.Parent = this;
        txtbox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        txtbox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
        txtbox.Multiline = true;
        txtbox.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;
        txtbox.AcceptsTab = true;
        txtbox.AppendText(a);
        txtbox.AppendText("\n");          
    }
}

class program1
 {

     public static void Main()
     {

        string result = "abc";

        while(true)
        {
            Application.Run(new NotepadCloneNoMenu(result));
     }
 }
 }
```

I want to continuously appending the string result to the textbox so it looks like this:

abc
abc
abc

so on and so forth. However, every time I called this:

```
Application.Run(new NotepadCloneNoMenu(result));
```

It will reset the textbox. Is there anyway I can update the textbox continuously? I am fairly new to C# so this is quite confusing to me.

thanks,
Phuc Pham

Comment: Start with something easier, like following a tutorial on making a WinForm applications. This is now WPF or a console app as your tags claim, it's WinForms. Look at the verbage of your code - wouldn't you read that as if you're trying to run a bunch of applications with the same root form? Not that you should be doing that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're continuously closing and opening an application. That's why it resets. If you want to run an infinite loop, you probably want to run it inside your application proper.

In your application code, use some event (maybe a timer would suit you) to append text to the textBox. Like this:

```
public someEventOnTheForm (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtBox.Text += "Notepad Clone to Menu";
}
```

There's two more things to take into account: first, if you don't have a stoping condition, this will just keep filling memory until you run out of it.

Second, windows forms run on only one thread by default. You'll be using that thread to update the textbox, so while it's appending text, the form itself will be unusable. It'll probably blank out during the event if it starts taking long. You'll need a second thread to handle the event if you want your form to be usable.

Comment: Thanks Renan for your answer. This form is waiting for debugging message sent from the FX3, a USB controller I'm using. That's why it doesn't have a stopping condition. Also, would one thread be sufficient enough since all the program does is posting the messages it's receiving from the FX3 anyways?

Comment: You should include that information in your question. If you're receiving messages from the debugger every once in a few seconds, it might be viable, yes. As long as that information is not too fast for you to read. Also I would use a console application instead.

Comment: I've already got the Console Applications works. However, my group wants me to use the forms since it looks nicer. Is there anyway I can keeps appending the newly received messages to my TextBox then?

Comment: Use a background worker thread to capture new text, and in this thread append to the textbox's text. I'm really sorry you've got that kind of user to satisfy, because what you'll have to do is so much more complicated than using a simple console...